# Is there a way to increase Rate limits on Azure DevOps?

Tags: git, azure, jenkins, azure-devops, azure-repos

We were using an on premise Jenkins against an on premise GitBlit. This worked fine. Last week we migrated from GitBlit to Azure DevOps.

Our Jenkins Jobs now run with the PAT of a 'fake' Azure Account (not the 'Build Service Account' because that one can't be used by an on premise Jenkins). So for Azure DevOps this is a regular user. We found no other way to set this up. Using the PAT of an employee was not really a good option.

Problem now is that we are constantly hitting the Rate Limites with following error:

> Request was blocked due to exceeding usage of resource 'ATCPU' in
> namespace 'VSID'. For more information on why your request was
> blocked, see the topic "Rate limits" on the Microsoft Web site
> (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=823950).

[image]

After which the Jenkins Job fails.

This is a game stopper in our migration to Azure DevOps because there seems to be no way to adjust those Rate limits for a given user...

Do you have recommendations? Is there a way to increase those limits?

In the screenshot, what does the Count and TSTUs exactly mean? We have the idea that it's not about how many bytes are transferred but rather the number of Git Operations.

Our Jenkins Jobs mainly clone Git Repositories with the usage of local mirrors.

Answer (score 1):

This was a major block to our AZDO migration project as well.!

I don't know how and what is the implementation na architecture of your migration , but
what we actually did is to optimize the code, the code will timeout itself every 20 api calls, and also we were managing something like 4 PATs (users) for the migration, the code was replacing the PAT every 100 calls or something like this.

you can also try reaching out to the Microsoft Azure help service and create ticket. they helped us a lot with opening the queue.

As for [TSTUs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rate-limits?view=azure-devops)

> TSTUs eventually incorporate a blend of the following:
>
> - Azure SQL Database DTUs as a measure of database consumption
> - Application tier and job agent CPU, memory, and I/O as a measure of
>   compute consumption
> - Azure Storage bandwidth as a measure of storage consumption.
>
> For now, TSTUs are primarily focused on Azure SQL Database
> DTUs, since Azure SQL Databases are the shared resources most commonly
> overwhelmed by excessive consumption.
>
> A single TSTU is the average load we expect a single normal user of
> Azure DevOps to generate per five minutes. Normal users also generate
> spikes in load. These spikes are typically 10 or fewer TSTUs per five
> minutes. Less frequently, spikes go as high as 100 TSTUs. The global
> consumption limit is 200 TSTUs within a sliding five-minute window.

I personally am not familiar with GitBlit, If you manage there issues (work items) and tests, you need to have good and focused queries, to optimize the data transfer.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by optimize the code and timeout itself every 20 api calls? How do you track the number of api calls you did for instance... And by code do you mean jenkins jobs? Thx for the answer!

Comment: @LievenCardoen As i said, i am not familiar with the implementation and architecture of your migration process, we developed a nodejs application to perform the migration step by step. how did you perform the migration with jenkins ? api calls ? external tools ?

Comment: FYI MS has changed their stance on rate limiting exceptions. To qualify you will need to open a ticket; however, I have heard they are very limited on granting exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Formally MS could give an exception, but now they will only ask you to purchase 'Basic + Test Plans', which can be found under your organization settings. If you still exceed the limitation, they will suggest you optimize your code.